# Как получить Dom элемент после отрисовки всех элементов?

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, fetch

У меня есть блок div teams я туда с помощью fetch отрисую все команды.
Но когда хочу получить в коде этот блок teams, я получаю пустой блок без команды

[image: Код Js файла]
[image: Консоль]

Как написать чтобы отрисовался полностью блок teams и выполнялись остальные команды

Comment: Пожалуйста, не прикрепляйте код картинкой (править вопрос можно, нажав кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1490737/edit)).

Comment: Приведите код полностью

Comment: *"Но когда хочу получить в коде этот блок teams, я получаю пустой блок без команды"* --- потому что ты в консоль выводишь данные **ВНЕ fetch** и **ВНЕ получения каких-либо данных**....... отрисовки данных тут в коде, кстати, не представлено

Comment: Почитайте про то как работает асинхронный код в js. Вы печатаете результат в консоль, когда результата еще нет. Если Вы хотите получить команду после записи данных в блок .team, вам нужно это делать в функции fetch следующим .then И предоставьте код showTeams()

Comment: @VladimirChistov скажите спасибо, что скриншот нормального качества, а не фотография монитора в 240p